# Can the Scrying spell target a location on another plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting, planes, divination

The description of the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell states:

> You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you.
>
> [...]
>
> Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn’t move.

The spell does not explicitly state that the location chosen must be on the same plane of existence, seemingly implying that that restriction holds only for targeting creatures.

**Can *scrying* target a location on another plane?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### *Scrying* is limited to targets on the same plane

The part of the [*scrying*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/scrying) spell that lets you target a location says that you target a location "instead of targeting a creature". This indicates that unless otherwise noted, any the restrictions on which creatures you can target also apply to scrying on locations – the only thing that changes is the type of the target. This means that the requirement for the target to be on the same plane of existence applies to all valid targets for the spell.